# Problema em retornar/salvar em uma lista em JAVA

Tags: java, array, lista, eclipse, joptionpane

Boa noite,

Tenho uma classe Principal:

```
        import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

        public class Principal {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                List<Imovel> lista1 = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Locacao> lista2 = new ArrayList<>();

                Imovel imovel = new Imovel(0, 0, 0, false);

                Imobiliaria imobiliaria = new Imobiliaria();

                int opcao = 0;

                do {
                    try {
                        opcao = parseInt(showInputDialog(Imobiliaria.menu()));
                        if(opcao < 1 || opcao >6) {
                            throw new OpcaoInvalidaException("Opcao Invalida");
                        } else {
                            switch(opcao) {
                            case 1: 
                                Imobiliaria.registrarImovel(imovel);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Imobiliaria.ListarDisponivel(lista1);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }
                    catch(OpcaoInvalidaException e) {
                        showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }

                } while(opcao != 6);
            }

        }
```

E tenho uma classe chamada Imovel :

```
        public class Imovel {
            private int codigo;
            private int metragem;
            private double valorMetroQuadrado;
            private boolean disponivel;

            public Imovel(int codigo, int metragem, double valorMetroQuadrado, boolean disponivel) {
                super();
                this.codigo = codigo;
                this.metragem = metragem;
                this.valorMetroQuadrado = valorMetroQuadrado;
                this.disponivel = disponivel;
                disponivel = true;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                String aux = "";
                String dispo = "O quarto está disponivel";
                aux += "O codigo do imovel é " + codigo + "\n";
                aux += "A metragem do imovel é " + metragem + "\n";
                aux += "O valor do metro quadrado é " + valorMetroQuadrado + "\n";
                if(disponivel == false) {
                    dispo =  "O quarto não está disponivel";
                }
                aux += dispo;

                return aux;
            }

            public int getCodigo() {
                return codigo;
            }

            public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
                this.codigo = codigo;
            }

            public int getMetragem() {
                return metragem;
            }

            public void setMetragem(int metragem) {
                this.metragem = metragem;
            }

            public double getValorMetroQuadrado() {
                return valorMetroQuadrado;
            }

            public void setValorMetroQuadrado(double valorMetroQuadrado) {
                this.valorMetroQuadrado = valorMetroQuadrado;
            }

            public boolean isDisponivel() {
                return disponivel;
            }

            public void setDisponivel(boolean disponivel) {
                this.disponivel = disponivel;
            }

        }
```

Uma classe Comercial:

```
        public class Comercial extends Imovel {
            private int numeroDeSalas;


            public Comercial(int codigo, int metragem, double valorMetroQuadrado, boolean disponivel, int numeroDeSalas) {
                super(codigo, metragem, valorMetroQuadrado, disponivel);
                this.numeroDeSalas = numeroDeSalas;
            }


            @Override
            public String toString() {
                String aux = "";
                aux += "O numero de sala é " + numeroDeSalas + "\n";

                return aux;
            }


            public int getNumeroDeSalas() {
                return numeroDeSalas;
            }


            public void setNumeroDeSalas(int numeroDeSalas) {
                this.numeroDeSalas = numeroDeSalas;
            }

            public double calcularAluguel() {
                return getMetragem()*getValorMetroQuadrado()+550*getNumeroDeSalas();
            }

        }
```

Outra classe chamada Residencial:

```
        public class Residencial extends Imovel {
            private int numeroDeQuartos;

            public Residencial(int codigo, int metragem, double valorMetroQuadrado, boolean disponivel, int numeroDeQuartos) {
                super(codigo, metragem, valorMetroQuadrado, disponivel);
                this.numeroDeQuartos = numeroDeQuartos;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                String aux = "";
                aux += "O numero de quartos é " + numeroDeQuartos + "\n";

                return aux;
            }

            public int getNumeroDeQuartos() {
                return numeroDeQuartos;
            }

            public void setNumeroDeQuartos(int numeroDeQuartos) {
                this.numeroDeQuartos = numeroDeQuartos;
            }

            public double calcularAluguel() {
                return getMetragem()*getValorMetroQuadrado()+300*getNumeroDeQuartos();
            }

        }
```

e por fim a mais importante Imobiliaria

```
        import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Iterator;
        import java.util.List;

        import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
        import static java.lang.Long.parseLong;
        import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog;
        import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;


        public class Imobiliaria {

            private static List<Imovel> lista1 = new ArrayList<Imovel>();

            private static List<Locacao> lista2 = new ArrayList<Locacao>();

            private static Residencial residencial = new Residencial(0, 0, 0, false, 0);


            static String menu() {
                String aux = "";
                aux += "1 - Registrar Imovel \n";
                aux += "2 - Listar Imoveis disponiveos \n";
                aux += "3 - Listar Imoveis ALUGADOS \n";
                aux += "4 - Realizar Locação \n";
                aux += "5 - Finalizar Locação \n";
                aux += "6 - Finalizar \n";

                return aux;
            }

            public static void registrarImovel(Imovel imovel) throws OpcaoInvalidaException {
                int codigo, metragem,opcao = 0,numeroDeQuartos,numeroDeSalas;
                boolean disponivel;
                double valorMetroQuadrado;


                opcao = parseInt(showInputDialog("Qual tipo de imovel?\n1. Residencial\n2. Comercial"));
                if(opcao < 1 ||opcao > 2) {
                    throw new OpcaoInvalidaException("Opcao Invalida");
                } else if(opcao == 1) {
                    codigo = parseInt(showInputDialog("Digite o código do imovel"));

                    metragem = parseInt(showInputDialog("Digite a metragem do imovel"));

                    valorMetroQuadrado = parseInt(showInputDialog("Digite o valor do metro quadrado"));

                    numeroDeQuartos = parseInt(showInputDialog("Digite o numero de quartos"));

                    disponivel = true;

                    lista1.add(new Residencial(codigo, metragem, valorMetroQuadrado, disponivel, numeroDeQuartos));
                }

                else {
                    codigo = parseInt(showInputDialog("Digite o código do imovel"));

                    metragem = parseInt(showInputDialog("Digite a metragem do imovel"));

                    valorMetroQuadrado = parseInt(showInputDialog("Digite o valor do metro quadrado"));

                    numeroDeSalas = parseInt(showInputDialog("Digite o numero de quartos"));

                    disponivel = true;

                    lista1.add(new Comercial(codigo, metragem, valorMetroQuadrado, disponivel, numeroDeSalas));
                }


            }

            public static void ListarDisponivel(List<Imovel> lista1) {
                String ListarResidencial = "";
                String ListarComercial;


                ListarResidencial += "IMOVEIS RESIDENCIAL -----------------";

                for(Imovel imovel : lista1) {
                    ListarResidencial += "teste";
                    ListarResidencial += imovel.getCodigo();
                    ListarResidencial += imovel.getMetragem();
                    ListarResidencial += imovel.getValorMetroQuadrado();
                    ListarResidencial += residencial.getNumeroDeQuartos();
                }

                showMessageDialog(null, ListarResidencial);
            }

        }
```

Na classe Imobiliaria existe um menu em que eu crio e pergunto se é residencial ou comercial ai eu pego os dados e adiciono na lista com lista.add

porem apos isso eu tento retornar esses dados, mas os dados nao sao retornados, nem null nao aparece nada apenas fecha...

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

No seu método principal vc está passando uma lista vazia na chamada do método `Imobiliaria.ListarDisponivel(lista1);` e é em cima dessa lista que o método da classe `Imobiliaria` está trabalhando.

A lista na qual vc está adicionando os valores, é a da classe `Imobiliaria`, portanto vc não precisa passar nada no método. Altere o seu método `ListarDisponivel` para:

```java
    public static void listarDisponivel() {
                String ListarResidencial = "";
                String ListarComercial;


                ListarResidencial += "IMOVEIS RESIDENCIAL -----------------";

                for(Imovel imovel : lista1) {
                    ListarResidencial += "teste";
                    ListarResidencial += imovel.getCodigo();
                    ListarResidencial += imovel.getMetragem();
                    ListarResidencial += imovel.getValorMetroQuadrado();
                    ListarResidencial += residencial.getNumeroDeQuartos();
                }

                showMessageDialog(null, ListarResidencial);
            }
```

E a chamada do método na sua classe principal ficará:

```java
Imobiliaria.ListarDisponivel();
```

Dessa forma ele fará a iteração na lista da sua classe e não na lista recebida por parâmetro.

Gostaria de comentar mais algumas coisas que reparei no seu código, caso seja de seu interesse e vc não tenha reparado:

> 1) Vc não precisa instanciar as listas e a classe `Imobiliaria` na sua classe `Principal`, uma vez que sua classe `Imobiliaria` possui métodos `static` e vc trabalhará com as listas presentes nela. Portanto pode remover esses trechos de código da sua classe `Principal`:

```java
List<Imovel> lista1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Locacao> lista2 = new ArrayList<>();

Imobiliaria imobiliaria = new Imobiliaria();
```

> 2) Na chamada do método `registrarImovel` ainda na sua classe `Imobiliaria`, vc está passando um `Imovel` como parâmetro que não está sendo usado. Não há necessidade.

E por fim uma dica: É boa prática declararmos métodos e variáveis em LowerCamelCase (Primeira letra minúscula), portanto seu método ficaria: `listarDisponivel`, por exemplo.

Espero ter ajudado.